# Помогите сделать сложную кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Есть SVG файл с дизайном кнопки - https://yadi.sk/d/ueGSqTix3U4tjc

Нужно чтобы получилась вот такая кнопка и работали все 3 кнопки (представить, наши презентации PDF, видео) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста как это все осуществить

Comment: Решение на чистом CSS не подойдет? Зачем для этого svg?

Comment: ты можешь в :before у блока справа сделать width: 10px и height: 10px (примерно) position:absolute, выровняй как тебе необходимо и на background-image поставь эту полукруглую картинку с треугольником) только у родителя position:relative не забудь указать

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Мой костыль, не знаю подойдет или нет. Без нужного шрифта, цвета и размеров.

```css
.wrapper {
 width: 500px;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
}

.left, .right {
 width: 50%;
 text-align: center;
}

.left span, .right span {
 color: #fff;
}

.left .button {
 border-right: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px;
}

.right .button {
 border-left: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
}

.button {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px 0;
 background: #ecd114;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-weight: bold;
 display: block;
 color: #000;
}

.button, .play {
 transition: .25s background ease;
} 

.button:hover, .play:hover {
 background: #ecc114;
}

.or-and-play {
 width: 138px;
 height: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 background: #ecd114;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.or-and-play:before, .or-and-play:after {
 content: '';
 width: 46px;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 background: #fff;
}

.or-and-play:before {
 border-radius: 0 25px 0 0;
 left: 0;
}

.or-and-play:after {
 border-radius: 25px 0 0 0;
 right: 0;
}

.or-and-play span, .play {
 position: absolute;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0);
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.or-and-play span {
 z-index: 2;
 font-size: 14px;
 left: 50%;
 top: -50%;
}

.play {
 width: 46px;
 padding: 15px 0;
 line-height: 1;
 background: #ecd114;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-radius: 50%;
 color: #000;
 top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="left">
  <a href="#" class="button">Представить</a>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  <a href="#" class="button">Наша презентация <span>PDF</span></a>
  <div class="or-and-play">
   <span>или</span>
   <a href="#" class="play">&#9658;</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш "костыль" идеально вписался в проект :)